# i cloned a project from an azure repo. How can i push it to a different repository ? Azure DevOps

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

i cloned a project from an azure repo. How can i push it to a different repository ? Azure DevOps. I tried doing it in visual studio but it just keeps on connecting to its original source

Comment: Are you only using Visual Studio for your git workflow? If so, what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I am using a visual studio 2019 community.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to push it to a different empty new repository, please follow below steps to do that.

[image]

1. Open Visual Studio 2019, **Git** -> **Local Repositories** -> Select
   the local cloned repo to open.
   [image]
2. Then go to **Git** -> **Manage Remotes** -> Select the origin remote
   to edit -> Change the remotes to the new empty repo

[image]
[image]

3. Open **Git changes** -> Click the **Push** button to push changes to
   the new repo.
   [image]
4. Check the changes in remote repo

[image]

If you are trying to push the cloned repo (e.g A) to an existing different repository (e.g B), then you can connect to the project and clone the repo B to local, and then copy sources from A to B, then push changes to B.